# Is apple $\cap$ {apple, orange} empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m newbie on set theory
I have read the definition of axiom of regularity on wikipedia, let X be {apple, orange}, am i right to say apple intersects {apple, orange} is empty, it will be wrong, it shows that it follows axiom of regularity, am I right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the axiom of regularity. If $A\subset B$ then $A\cap B=A.$ And $\{a\}\ne\varnothing.$

Comment: $apple\in\{apple\}$ and $apple\in\{apple,orange\},$ so their intersection contains $apple.$

Comment: The intersection of two sets $A$ and $B$ is a set $C$ that contains all and only the elements that are in both $A$ and $B$. In your case, apple is an element that is in both sets, and it is the only such element, so the intersection is {apple}.

Comment: So how do every non-empty set A( say A:= {a,b} , there exists an element that is disjoint from A, which means their intersection is empty,as b belongs to A, how come it will bring me empty set

Comment: $b$ and $A$ may be disjoint.  $\{b\}$ and $A$ never are.

Comment: Thanks Brian, now I change the question to formal answer

Comment: "If I interpret $\text{apple}$ as being $\{\text{apple}\}$ but not $\text{apple}$" is nonsense to me.  You seem to be contradicting both the law of identity and the axiom of regularity in this single phrase.

Comment: What Im trying to say is, Apple intersect {apple, orange} is empty, but {apple} isnt, did I misunderstand it

Comment: Any way it ends up being a stupid mistake, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=$ apple and $b=$ orange.
$$a\cap\{a,b\}\ne\varnothing\iff[(a\in a)\text{ or }(b\in a)].$$
Assuming the axiom of regularity, we derive that $a\cap\{a,b\}$ is empty if and only if $b\notin a.$

Comment: I like your reasoning, since a is restricted not to belong to a itself, and obviously b does not belong to a, it is therefore empty

Comment: No. $b$ can very well belong to $a.$ For instance $a=\{b\}$ like in Snared's answer, or $a=$ any larger set, like $\{b,\{b\}\},$ or $\{b,\varnothing\},$ or $\{b,\{b\},\varnothing\}$...

Answer (score 3):

Let the set X be defined as {apple,orange}, where apple is a set and orange is a set. Then, it is not the case that apple cap X is necessarily empty. Suppose apple = {orange}. Then, X is equal to {orange, {orange}}. Then, apple intersect X is equal to {orange} intersect {orange, {orange}} which is clearly nonempty as the intersection is equal to {orange}.

However, the intersection COULD also be empty. It simply depends on your definitions of apple and orange.

Comment: Alright, it makes sense, if i define apple being {orange}, as {orange, {orange}} has {orange}, therefore their intersection is non-empty.but if I define apple being apple, as this is an element but not a set, such that nothing belongs to it, its intersection with {apple, orange} will be empty

Comment: apple = {a}, orange = {o} such that apple intersect orange is empty. Then 1={a} intersect 2={{a}, {o}} is empty since a is the only element in 1, but $a$ not in 2. Rather, {a} in 2 is the important distinction here which makes the intersection empty in that case.

Comment: The way you formalize my idea is better than myself, i should work hard in proof-writing

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help